# How to Display GoogleMap(iam using map fragment) using API V2 in older version of android OS

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am in a project where i want to display the location of vehicle in Google map. I am getting the latitude and longitude of the vehicles from a Json web service and no problem in Diplaying the marker and setting the location.

My problem is that application is working fine on ICE CREAM SAND WITCH AND Jelly Bean OS mobiles, when i try to put the application in Gingerbread OS it is getting force closed.

In my application i am using the Map Fragment, and API V2.
I have added the android-support v 13 jar file to my library.

Here is my Manifest code.

```
enter code here

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
    />

    <permission 
    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/goo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Translucent" >
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDXAFrfJnmvVqOJFQ4w5WPajngNoeZpDMI"/>
    <activity
        android:name="info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.HelpActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Please any one help me how to run this application in older versions of android OS..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace `com.example.androidmapsv2` with your packagename in manifest.xml

then

use `SupportMapFragment` for <3.0 versions as fragment is available from API 11(3.0)

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

and your Activity class should looks like this

```
public class SupportMapFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_support_map_fragment);

    FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)fragment;
    GoogleMap supportMap = supportmapfragment.getMap();

  }

}
```

Comment: @Rag-android In addition to that also set minSdkVersion to 8 (or 9 depending on the Google Play Services client library version), because GPServices won't work pre-Froyo.