# Map View Crashing in lower version of Android OS

Tags: android, google-maps

I have followed the steps in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2 for implementing Map in android .

I have tested in Samsung Note II(Version 4.1.2) , Samsung 10.1" Tab(Version 4.0), i am getting the map correctly but when i tested in Samsung Galaxy Ace( Version 2.3.6 ), it is crashing . And i get the crash log

```
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package.name.classname}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package.name.classname}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-20 15:13:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know why and what is wrong . Won't it work on lower versions of Android ?

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: May this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089588/how-to-display-googlemapiam-using-map-fragment-using-api-v2-in-older-version-o

Comment: Post your Manifest file and xml here so that will give suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`.

Comment: And do you use FragmentActivity instead of a regular one?

Comment: Yes, i am using FragmentActivity . But if anything wrong it should have not run in higher version as well .

Comment: Strange, I have no problem with it, although I'm using SherlockFragmentActivity, but it should not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try it Brother:
in xml

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```